# Can Scipy's Optimization find Multiple Local Extrema?

Tags: optimization, scipy

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Finding Local Extema in Scipy's Gaussian KDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754263/finding-local-extema-in-scipys-gaussian-kde)

I've been trying to figure out how to use scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar, since it's specialized for functions of one variable, and provides a way for me to control the interval of interest. But when I tried to use it, I got only one extrema whereas for my actual application I'm going to need multiple.

Here's a simple example

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

def f(x):
    return x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)

minimum=minimize_scalar(f,bounds=(-1,4),method='bounded')
```

There are two local minima: One near x=0.382 and another near x=2.618; but only the first of these is reported.

Is there a way I can get it to report both (apart from manually changing the bounds to catch only minimum at a time, a luxury I won't have if I don't already know where the minima are)? Or a different function that will do that? In my actual application, I'm going to want it to report the 3 highest local maxima.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to resort to global optimization algorithms that can provide that information, but you still have to get lucky anyway. You may give AMPGO (a tunnelling strategy I wrote) a try and see if it gives you any insight.

AMPGO: https://github.com/andyfaff/ampgo/blob/master/%20ampgo%20--username%20andrea.gavana%40gmail.com/go_amp.py

Benchmarks: http://infinity77.net/global_optimization/multidimensional.html